# Point New domain contents to old domain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Using `htaccess` i have written to point old domain to new domain . but i need new domain page in old domain url.

The contents in the `test.xyz.com` has to be shown in old domain.

How can I achieve it  ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.test\.net$
Redirect 301 / https://test.xyz.com
```

Comment: Could you please provide links eg: FROM which link TO which link you want to redirect and of which domain contents you want? That will give better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: abc.test.net  is old domain which have old contents in that page ..   https://test.xyz.com is the new domain  with new contents ..

what i need is   old domain  should point to   new domain contents   but the url should be old domain  only .. is that possible ??

Comment: I understand that you want to keep the old domain in the addressbar of the browser, but still route requests to the new domain. That is _not_ possible via redirection (redirection _always_ changes the visible URL). You _can_ internally route those requests by using the internal proxy module of the http server. That works, but has disadvantages: you need the proxy and the proxy_http modules loaded into your http server and you need to accept a performance penalty, since each and every request results in a full additional internal request.